# device or resource busy: /dev/ttyUSB0 when not root

Tags: permissions, serial-port, arduino

I've got an arduino that I use `echo "b" >  /dev/ttyUSB0` to send data to it. When this command is run via the `root` user it works correctly.

However a normal user gets an error of:

```
echo 'b' >  /dev/ttyUSB0 
zsh: device or resource busy: /dev/ttyUSB0
```

How can I give a regular user permission for this?

```
ls -altr /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Nov 30 22:40 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

My user is in the `dialout` group, so they should have permission.

Comment: find whatever else is using `/dev/ttyUSB0` with `fuser` or `lsof`. Uninstall ModemManager (unless you're really using modem-like devices): `apt-get remove modemmanager`